# How can I use a loop that takes numerical input, prints the number until 'complete' is typed?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I need to write a code that uses a loop that will take numerical input, then print the number. It will do this infinitely until 'complete' is typed. Once 'complete' is typed, the average, count and sum of the numbers that were input will be printed. If another word ('stop' for instance) is typed instead of 'complete', the a message directing the user to input a number or 'complete' will print and restart the loop.

```
`import sys
count = 0
sumN = 0.0
line = 1

while True:
    line = (input('>>> '))
    sumN = sumN + float(line)
    count += 1
    try:
        if line == '#':
            sumN = sumN + float(line)
            count += 1
            print(line)
            continue
        elif line == 'done':
            print(float(line)) # to send to except
            break
        elif line != '#' and line != 'done':
            print("Please enter a number or 'done' to finish input:")
            continue
    except:
        print('The total sum of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN))
        print('The count of your inputs is: ' + str(count))
        print('The average of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN/count))`
```

Comment: This is what i tried but it does not work.

Comment: Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're trying to convert `input` into float before you enter the 'try catch' block.

```
import sys
count = 0
sumN = 0.0
line = 1

while True:
    line = (input('>>> '))
    try:
        sumN = sumN + float(line) <--- this was causing the issue
        count += 1
        if line == '#':
            sumN = sumN + float(line)
            count += 1
            print(line)
            continue
        elif line == 'done':
            print(float(line)) # to send to except
            break
        elif line != '#' and line != 'done':
            print("Please enter a number or 'done' to finish input:")
            continue
    except ValueError :
        print('The total sum of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN))
        print('The count of your inputs is: ' + str(count))
        print('The average of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN/count))
```

this should work. Notice the new position of the `try`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should say *why* it does not work.  Does it error, or does it complete but not give the correct behavior or data.

The main problem that I see is

```
        if line == '#':
            sumN = sumN + float(line)
```

The variable `line` is a string, holding the user's input. Saying 'line == "#"' does not test for line being a number.  Instead, you need do to do something like:

```
try:
   number = float(line) # Try to convert input into a number.
   sumN += number
   count += 1
except:
   print("Please enter a number or 'done', [%s] is not a number" # line)
   continue
```

This is a common practice in Python, try something, and handle error via exception.  You could also try searching for number characters in the line, but this gets messy if you want to allow decimal points, negative signs, etc.  You could check each character, but it is simpler to just try converting line into a number with float(), and handling the error if it occurs.

Also, you are incrementing the counter for every input.  Instead, you should only increment it if the user entered a number.

Comment: Thanks so much!

I took what you said and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
import sys

count = 0
sumN = 0.0

while True:
    line = input(">>> ")
    try:
        if line.isdigit():
            sumN += float(line)
            count += 1
            print(line)
        elif line == 'done':
            raise Exception()
        else:
            print("Please enter a number or 'done' to finish input:")
    except:
        print('The total sum of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN))
        print('The count of your inputs is: ' + str(count))
        print('The average of your inputs is: ' + str(sumN/count))
        break
```

you can check if a string is a number or not by using `str.isdigit()` function.